# Renaming successive folders and files in android

Tags: java, android, android-file

I have a file at location a/b/c.txt . I want to move this file to location d/e/f.txt .I want to rename the folder/directory a to d ,b to e and file c.txt to f.txt .How to do this in android?

```
public void moveFile(View view) {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "a" + File.separator + "b" + File.separator + "c.txt");
            if (file.exists()) {
                boolean res = file.renameTo(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + File.separator + "d" + File.separator + "e" + File.separator + "f.txt"));


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(res), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Prateek, did my answer help? A tick mark for an accepted answer is always nice to get, and might also be helpful for future readers of your question. If you have any doubts or questions still, feel free…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very much on the right track when you say “I want to rename the folder/directory a to d ,b to e and file c.txt to f.txt .” You just have to rename one directory at a time and the file itself separately:

```
    String externalStorageDirAbsPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File file = new File(externalStorageDirAbsPath + File.separator + "a" + File.separator + "b" + File.separator + "c.txt");
    if (file.exists()) {
        // first rename a to d
        boolean res = new File(externalStorageDirAbsPath + File.separator + "a")
                        .renameTo(new File(externalStorageDirAbsPath + File.separator + "d"));
        if (res) {
            // rename b to e
            res = new File(externalStorageDirAbsPath + File.separator + "d" + File.separator + "b")
                    .renameTo(new File(externalStorageDirAbsPath + File.separator + "d" + File.separator + "e"));
            if (res) {
                // rename c.txt to f.txt
                res = new File(externalStorageDirAbsPath + File.separator + "d" + File.separator + "e" + File.separator + "c.txt")
                        .renameTo(new File(externalStorageDirAbsPath + File.separator + "d" + File.separator + "e" + File.separator + "f.txt"));
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(res), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I have tested the central part of the code on Mac OS X. I have not tested on Android. If there’s a typo in the hand translation back to Android code, I hope you’ll be able to figure it out.

Instead of the `File` class you may want to look into the newer `java.nio.file` package, the `Path` class may give you a little convenience here, but I think you would still have to rename one directory at a time and the file separately, just as here.